# JTable AutoCreateRowSorter sorting Numbers As Strings

Tags: java, swing, jtable, comparator, rowsorter

I have a JTable:

```
JTable table = new JTable();
String[] colNames = {"c1"};
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();

Integer[] x = new Integer[10];
int[] xi = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
    x[i]=new Integer(xi[i]);
}model.addColumn("c1");

table.setModel(model);
table.setEnabled(false);
table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
contentPane.add(scrollpane);
```

Now when I load this and click on a column title the rows sort as if they were Strings:

0,10... (in order of length)

How can i change this so they order numerically?

Comment: Not related to the actual question. You should avoid using constructor of Integer class to create Integer objects. Always use `Integer.value(value)` method to create Integer object as it caches frequently used values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the `RowSorter` calls `TableModel.getColumnClass(int index)` to get the `Class` associated to the column in `index` position and use its `Comparator` to do the sort.

`DefaultTableModel` extends from `AbstractTableModel` and doesn't override `getColumnClass(int columnIndex)` method:

```
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
    return Object.class;
}
```

As you can see it always return `Object.class`. To properly sort your column, you need to override `getColumnClass` method.

Answer (score 4):

> How can i change this so they order numerically?

Override the `getColumnClass()` method of your TableModel to return `Integer.class` and the Integer Comparator will be used to sort the data instead of the String comparator.

Comment: @clairharrison, search the forum/web for the method name I just gave you. You will find plenty of examples. I sure hope dic19 does not write the code for you because you won't learn anything unless you try to do it yourself. Overriding methods is very common in Java so the sooner you learn how to do it the better. In fact if you read the Swing API for JTable you will find a link to the Swing tutorial on `How to Use Tables` which contains an example.